# CSS Text Shadow / Indent

Tags: css

Does anyone know the CSS or tut for the style to make this type of text shadow/indent?

A google search for css text shadow/indent is not bringing it up...

I couldn't post the image inline so here's the direct link: http://i.minus.com/ibr0BdDsx0IaBT.png

Answer (score 2):

The CSS for it should be something like this:

```
text-shadow: -1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
```

Link: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-shadow.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
```

meaning

```
text-shadow: x-position y-position shadow-size shadow-color;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the page the screenshot is comming from with FireBug, you could have found that the effect is made with:

```
#footer-wrap #footer .foot-col {
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete CSS3 shadow tut and many examples - http://bit.ly/WKd65x

Answer (score 0):

Might this works for you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1 {
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black, 0 0 25px blue, 0 0 5px darkblue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Text-shadow effect!</h1>

<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, do not support the text-shadow property.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the source: [CSS Text & Font Properties](https://www.brotsky.tv/2014/10/04/building-a-website-part-7-css-text-font-properties/)

Comment: Links tend to change or go missing, could you explain some of the contents or quote it here?